# Android Masks with two images

Tags: android, android-studio, mask

I'm looking for recommendations on how to do this, I've been trying with a couple of ideas with no luck.

**I have this mask**:

[image]

**And this image**:

[image]

**end result should be**:

[image]

I just want to change the color of the image with the mask.

## Update: 01/22:

After a couple of tries, I made some progress.
Here is my current code:

```
Bitmap carBaseBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), model);
Bitmap maskBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), overlay);
Bitmap finalFinal = Bitmap.createBitmap(maskBitmap.getWidth(), maskBitmap.getHeight(),  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalFinal);

ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
float[] colorTransform = getCarColor();
colorMatrix.set(colorTransform);
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.OVERLAY));

paint.setColorFilter(filter);

canvas.drawBitmap(carBaseBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, paint);
```

getColor method returns:

```
float[] colorFilter = {
    1, 0, 0, 0, 20,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 61,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 184,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
};
```

**and the end results is**:

[image]

Comment: you want to change only the door color in the picture below, is that it?

Comment: Sorry, @nandsito. I added the end result.

Comment: maybe you can achieve it by playing around with `Canvas`, `Paint`, `Bitmap` and `Drawable` classes and drawing then directly onto `View.onDraw()` but you'll end up with a flat color, like a wall paint. Those curves in lighter blue that yield the 3D perspective will be very hard to do, I presume